# Rewrite ignoring files in a directory when it exists

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have been using successfully the following rewrite that takes www.site.com/123/abc to points it to www.site.com/index.php?id=123&page=abc

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Until now. When a directory that exists and matches the $1 www.site.com/123/ the files in the /123/ directory I no have access to. If I try changing the rewrite to the following everything stills works except the files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

What would one use to keep using mod rewrite and not ignore files in a directory when it exists.

Comment: Let me try explaining my scenario this way. I have a URL site.com/123/ there is no directory 123 which mod rewrite points to site.com/index.php?id=123 New scenario comes into play, I now have URLs as in site.com/456/ there is a directory as well it is called 456. There is no php scripting in this directory just MP3 and images. Which means I still need mod rewrite to point to site.com/index.php?id=456 as above but still have access to those files when the index.php loads – right now it doesn’t. This is where I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond`s only apply to the very next `RewriteRule`. Since you have two rules you need to repeat your conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Or you could filter out files and directories at the top before continuing with your rewrite rules:

```
# Do nothing if URL points to existing file or directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Now that I did not know. However I tried it and I can pull images from the directory when it exists - unfortunately it breaks the rewrite rule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 which draws the file with all all the scripting.

Comment: Let me try explaining my scenario this way. I have a URL site.com/123/ there is no directory 123 which mod rewrite points to site.com/index.php?id=123


New scenario comes into play, I now have URLs as in site.com/456/ there is a directory as well it is called 456. There is no php scripting in this directory just MP3 and images. Which means I still need mod rewrite to point to site.com/index.php?id=456 as above but still have access to those files when the index.php loads – right now it doesn’t.

This is where I am stuck.